# Quaternion Rotation Between Two Sets of Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, rotation, quaternions

I would like some help on finding the rotation between two sets of two vectors in 3D as a quaternion. In each pair, the vectors would be at right angles to each other and have unit length (basically two vectors in an orthonormal basis).

My current code looks something like this:

```
Vector3 look1, up1, right1, look2, up2, right2;
// look1, up1, right1 form orthonormal basis,
// ditto with look2, up2, and right2
Vector3 lookRotateAxis = look1 % look2;
// operator% defined as cross product for convenience
float lookRotateAngle = acos(look1 * look2);
// operator* defined as dot product for convenience
Quaternion lookRotate;
lookRotate.makeRotation(lookRotateAngle, lookRotateAxis);
up1Transformed = lookRotate.rotateVector(up1);
Vector3 upRotateAxis = up1Transformed % up2;
float upRotateAngle = up1Transformed * up2;
Quaternion upRotate;
upRotate.makeRotation(upRotateAngle, upRotateAxis);
Quaternion finalRotation = upRotate * lookRotate;
// quaternion finalRotation rotates basis 1 to basis 2
```

The method I use right now is to find the quaternion rotation between the two vectors first of each pair, and then multiply by the quaternion rotation between the two vectors second of each pair. This results in a single quaternion that I can rotate both vectors by to get the other two vectors. Is there a simpler way to compute the quaternion, not by multiplying the two rotations, but computing a single rotation?

Thank you!

Comment: Without code to look at, this is purely a math question...and so "doing it faster" can only be answered in a very abstract mathematical way...people who don't know the math can't help with general performance coding tweaks.  As this is a programming site, could you edit your question (via the EDIT button) to provide what you have written now in the form of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  *(In early questions it is best to live by the rule "include some code", and only bend that later on with a sense of what kinds of non-code-including questions are considered on topic...)*

Comment: @HostileFork Thanks for the advice, I will consider editing. I am not new to this site, my old account was accidentally destroyed maliciously.

Comment: @Josh if it was done maliciously, it wasn't accidentally. Bummer either way. =(

Comment: @HostileFork Updated code. Not sure if it's perfect, currently unable to copy-paste from my workspace.

Comment: @Josh That's some code, which is an improvement...but an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be something people can paste into a compiler and get to run.  It looks fairly contained... can you give a version of Quaternion that has *only* what is needed to implement `makeRotation` and `rotateVector`, a definition for Vector3, and a simple invocation of a rotation on a sample vectors inside of an `int main()`?

Comment: @HostileFork It would be fairly time-consuming. I was banking on the fact that most people know that Vector3 would be defined as a class with fields x, y, and z, and a Quaternion being defined as a class with fields w, x, y, and z. I also assumed knowledge of rotating a vector around a quaternion (qpq`), and making a rotation quaternion (e.g. (1, 0, 0, 0) being the identity). If a person is not familiar with this vector and quaternion math, I would not expect them to answer my question. In addition, stuffing the whole block of code inside ``int main()`` would likely do the trick.

Comment: @WhozCraig Not really in to pop-culture, are you? That was a quote.

Comment: @Josh not really into popular *anything*.

Comment: @Josh In questions of performance in C++, small details in your implementation can make a significant difference.  Some ways of calling things will generate copies, others won't.  Details and specifics matter.  As I said, if you want to ask a **C++ question** vs a **math question** then the code is essential.  If you are skeptical of the time it would cost you to create a full isolated example, how are people answering supposed to cost their time?  Code also makes the question potentially more valuable for future searchers...who may well outnumber you by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @HostileFork I'm sorry for the confusion. This is not a performance question, I will edit my entry.

Comment: I got my account back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's possible to do what you want very quickly and efficiently. First thing, you should complete each orthonormal pair of vectors into an orthonormal basis. The obvious way to do so is by taking the cross product of the first two vectors. Order matters: if you want u0 to map to v0 and u1 to map to v1, then form the orthonormal basis {u0,u1,u2} where u2 = u0 x u1 (cross product), also form the orthonormal basis {v0,v1,v2} where v2 = v0 x v1, and map u2 to v2. If you weren't careful and set v2 = v1 x v0, you'd end up with an impossible situation (trying to map a right-handed coordinate system to a left-handed coordinate system with a rotation). So be careful about the order of terms in cross products.

Now that you have two orthonormal bases, or **frames**, it's easy to construct orthogonal matrices representing rotations from the {x,y,z} frame to the given frame. (Again, you have to give some thought to the orientation or handedness of the {x,y,z} frame ... you may have to use {x,z,y} instead, for example.) The matrix multiplication by an orthogonal matrix representing a rotation from the frame {x,y,z} to {u0,u1,u2} is

```
[u00 u01 u02]
[u10 u11 u12]
[u20 u21 u22]
```

where, according to the usual convention for computer graphics, we pre-multiply a vector by our matrix. So for example, the effect of our matrix on (1,0,0) is

```
        [u00 u01 u02]
[1 0 0] [u10 u11 u12] = [u00 u01 u02]
        [u20 u21 u22]
```

which is just what we want; the same for the other two basis vectors in {x,y,z}.

To map one frame to another, we go through the frame {x,y,z} as an intermediary. So we have to find the inverse of the first orthogonal matrix. Fortunately inverting an orthogonal matrix is very easy: you just take the transpose. So to map the frame {u0,u1,u2} to the frame {v0,v1,v2}, use the matrix product

```
[u00 u10 u20] [v00 v01 v02]
[u01 u11 u21] [v10 v11 v12]
[u02 u12 u22] [v20 v21 v22]
```

Let's see what happens when we input the vector u1 = [u10,u11,u12] into this matrix product:

```
              [u00 u10 u20] [v00 v01 v02]           [v00 v01 v02]
[u10 u11 u12] [u01 u11 u21] [v10 v11 v12] = [0 1 0] [v10 v11 v12] = [v10 v11 v12]
              [u02 u12 u22] [v20 v21 v22]           [v20 v21 v22]
```

just as required. Here we have used the formulas u1 . u0 = 0, u1 . u1 = 1, u1 . u2 = 0 which follow from {u0,u1,u2} being an orthonormal frame.

So the orthogonal matrix representing the rotation you want is exactly

```
[u00 u10 u20] [v00 v01 v02]
[u01 u11 u21] [v10 v11 v12]
[u02 u12 u22] [v20 v21 v22]
```

Perform the matrix multiplication to get a single matrix, then if you want the quaternion representation, convert from rotation matrix to quaternion by something like the method described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion.

Comment: Before I decided to use Quaternions, I was using matrices and doing basically this. Converting matrices to quaternions is perfectly valid, and I guess the biggest reason I'm reluctant to use this is that I seem to remember matrix-to-quaternion conversion being a gosh-awful ugly piece of code... not that it's inefficient, necessarily. It's not THAT bad, now that I look at it again... Thanks for the reply!